# What is wrong with this rescue example?

Tags: ruby, exception, rescue

```
x = StandardError.new(:hello)
y = StandardError.new(:hello)
x == y # => true
x === y # => true

begin
  raise x
rescue x
  puts "ok" # gets printed
end

begin
  raise x
rescue y
  puts "ok" # doesn't get printed
end
```

Why isn't the second "ok" printed? I can't figure it out. I've read [here](http://www.amp.carboni.ca/blog/p/Ruby-Did-You-Know-That-2-Exception-Handling) that ruby uses the `===` operator to match exceptions to rescue clauses, but that's ostensibly not the case.

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3

EDIT: So it seems like that after doing `raise x`, `x == y` and `x === y` no longer hold. It seems to because `x` and `y` [no longer have the same backtrace](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Exception.html#method-i-3D-3D).

Comment: No, that means "catch any StandardError and subclasses, and put the instance into the variable y". `y` is not interpreted as a value (as I want it to be), but as a variable name.

Comment: I think if you're trying to do pattern matches on RFID tags, the `raise / catch` idiom might not be the clearest way to go.  What about a `case` statement or dynamic dispatch using patterns?

Comment: The application has some "low-level" logic which communicates with the card. This is where the exceptions are thrown. Above that is some higher level, applicative logic. Some of the errors returned by the tag are actually fairly high level (stuff like "the file already exists on the tag") and must bubble back up to the user. Exceptions seem the best option for this.

Comment: Why not use an `RFIDException` class and attach whatever additional error info you need when you raise the exception `raise RFIDException, "additional info"`. Then rescue this exception and apply whatever processing is needed in the rescue block. If you need to bubble the error upwards just reraise the same exception. You are "abusing" rescue mechanics by not rescuing an `Exception` class. I don't think it is specced for what you want to do.

Comment: This would work if all exceptions needed to be handled in the same place. I would `rescue RFIDException` then do `case exception.type` or something like that and handle that. Unfortunately, different errors must be handled at different level in the call stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just want to add something to the table: OP code suggests that the two exceptions are the same but they are not - furthermore i want to illustrate what OP meant with:

> So it seems like that after doing raise x, x == y and x === y no longer hold. It seems to because x and y no longer have the same backtrace.

```
 x = StandardError.new(:hello)
 y = StandardError.new(:hello)
 class Object
   def all_equals(o)
     ops = [:==, :===, :eql?, :equal?]
     Hash[ops.map(&:to_s).zip(ops.map {|s| send(s, o) })]
   end
 end

 puts x.all_equals y # => {"=="=>true, "==="=>true, "eql?"=>false, "equal?"=>false}

 begin
   raise x
 rescue
   puts "ok" # gets printed
 end

 puts x.all_equals y # => {"=="=>false, "==="=>false, "eql?"=>false, "equal?"=>false}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that's a bug, or rather an underspecification of Ruby 1.9. Note that Ruby 2.0 raises  a

```
TypeError: class or module required for rescue clause
```

on lines 8 and 14.

Note that the `raise` doesn't necessarily do what you think it does, either. When you `raise` an object, you don't actually raise *that* object, you raise a *new* object which is constructed from the object you passed according to these simple rules:

- if the object responds to `exception`, call `exception` on the object and raise the return value
- if the object is a subclass of `Exception`, call `new` and raise the return value
- otherwise fail
- also fail if the return value of any of the above methods is not an instance of `Exception`

So, you are *not* actually raising `x`, you are raising `x.exception`. According to the documentation of `Exception#exception` `x.exception` is `x`, though.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: To clarify the issue for future responses, because I think my response is incorrect, the subtlety here is that `x` and `y` are *instances* rather than *classes*, and normally you would use classes in a `raise` statement.

---

If the intended behavior is to print at the second rescue, the `y` will not do the trick.  You are raising an exception of class `x`, and you don't have a rescue clause that will handle `x`. You would see "ok" printed for the second block if you caught `StandardError`, the common base class, though:

```
begin
  raise x
rescue StandardError
  puts "ok"
end
```

Regarding #===, I think the issue is that when you raise, you're dealing with an *instance* of `x` rather than `x` as a class.

Comment: I know that, but it's not my question. My question is "why does  `rescue x` catch `x` while `rescue y` does not?". You did not explain why `rescue x` catches `x`. Also you have a typo in your answer, since I don't "raise an exception of class `x`" (`x` is simply the variable holding the exception, which is of class `StandardError`). I'm not sure what you meant.

Comment: @Norswap: `x` is a variable holding a reference to a class.  The thing that is caught is an instance of that class.

Comment: No it does not hold a reference to a class. `x.class => StandardError`. It is an instance of class `StandardError`.

Comment: @Norswap: you might be right -- I'll do some more reading. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the definition for rescue is:

```
[rescue [error_type [=> var],..]
```

Neither `x` nor `y` is stricly an `error_type`. They are instances of an error type. I don't think you're really running valid code the way you're doing it there.

If you run:

```
begin
  raise x
rescue y.class
  puts "ok"
end
```

Then it will work as expected.

Also note that on Ruby 1.8 neither `x == y` nor `x === y` returns `true`.

Comment: @Norswap But still; what exactly are you trying to do? I'm assuming you're just playing around, because what you are essentially doing is like saying `rescue 1`. It doesn't make any sense. You're supposed to rescue classes, not instances.

Comment: @Casper: I think the code is valid (i.e., if it compiles, which it does).  Whether it's clear is a different question.  But I don't think that's relevant to the question.

Comment: I'm building an application around an RFID reader. When communicating with an RFID tag, some opcodes may be returned, indicating errors. I want to be able to "catch" particular errors; but without having to create a new Exception class for each error (which is burdensome). So my idea was to do "pattern-matching" with rescue: I want to catch Exceptions of some classes which satisfies some condition. The condition I'm after here is whether some field of the class has the value I wish.

Comment: The 1.9 pickaxe book says "For each rescue clause in the begin block, Ruby compares the raised exception against each of the parameters in turn. If the raised exception matches a parameter, Ruby executes the body of the rescue and stops looking. The match is made using parameter===$!". So I think the construction is valid.

I've also put my finger on something. See edit in the question. So I guess the question is answered :/ Too bad for me.